# Sock-puppetry versus personal friends?

Tags: discussion

So, my best friend and daughter are members on this site.  Generally they "stalk" me, and I appreciate their votes and such, however I am afraid that they may appear as "sock-puppets" to others.  Which got me thinking, is there a way to monitor sock-puppetry?  How does StackExchange deal with that?

Comment: FYI - on Wikipedia there is a name for this: "[Meat-puppetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Sock_puppetry#Meatpuppetry)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Larian, we noticed that oddity a month or so ago, but it was apparent to us that they were legit users. There's nothing wrong if you share your IP with other **real** people. In your case I can see 3 other users sharing your IP.

However, they are up voting you too much, and they are triggering our anti-serial-voting script. This is also the reason why you saw your rep drop. The cause of the drop is not down votes, but invalid up votes being cleared.

This has happened 5 times so far:

- May 14
- May 3
- Apr 24
- Apr 23
- Apr 3

Please have a chat with your daughter and friend(s), and explain to them that serial up voting doesn't help you and that it's actually counterproductive in the long run.

Comment: Thanks.  Will chat with my daughter (who is usually sitting next to me as I do StackExchange).  As for the other user, he was visiting when I introduced him to StackExchange.  Now he's coming from another IP I'm sure, and I'll email him as well.

Comment: Oh, and actually this isn't the exact same question.  The other question showed actual downvotes on answers given in my profile (as opposed to adjustments).  Would you be so kind as to open that one back up again if anyone else feels they are being targeted.

Comment: @Larian You only got 2 recent downvotes, there is no blanket downvoting of your posts happening. If you still want to know about the mechanisms that prevent serial-downvoting, I can reopen the question (just saw it was merged, so you couldn't edit it, I unlocked it now). You would need to edit it a bit, as the reputation loss you mentioned was not caused by downvotes.

Comment: No not MINE in particular, it just got me thinking about other people.  :)  Sorry if I wasn't clear on that.

Comment: Oops.  Sorry about that...  And I may have tripped the thing today as well.  Sorry, haven't checked my email today.  Ah, Larian deserves all the harassment he can get!  :)

Comment: I'll pay you back next time you want some of my homemade Mead.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, make sure that your friends and family vote on a variety of posts, *not just yours*.

Any long sequence of votes from one user to another -- up or down -- tends to trigger our daily voting anomaly detector.